# Custom Module back end keeps coming up as a 404

Tags: backend, module, 404

I've added a Custom Module with front end and backend (adminhtml). Fornt end works fine but
back end throws 404 when going to the newly added menu item. THe chanegs to the backend menu do appear - the URL it goes to /index.php/accessdek/adminhtml_accessdesk throws a 404
Need to know what I can do from here to diagnose?

1. I have cleared cache and logged in and out of admin- the issue still persists
2. I have read Alan Storm's articles on Custom Modules- Unfortunately to no avail

Here is code for adminHTML in path
\app\code\local\Body1\AccessDesk\controllers\Adminhtml

class Body1_AccessDesk_Adminhtml_AccessDeskController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
{

```
protected function _initAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('accessdesk/items')
        ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Items Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));
    return $this;
}    

public function indexAction() {
    $this->_initAction();        
    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('accessdesk/adminhtml_accessdesk'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function editAction()
{
    $accessdeskId     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $accessdeskModel  = Mage::getModel('accessdesk/accessdesk')->load($accessdeskId);

    if ($accessdeskModel->getId() || $accessdeskId == 0) {

        Mage::register('accessdesk_data', $accessdeskModel);

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('accessdesk/items');

        $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));
        $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'));

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('accessdesk/adminhtml_accessdesk_edit'))
             ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('accessdesk/adminhtml_accessdesk_edit_tabs'));

        $this->renderLayout();
    } else {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('accessdesk')->__('Item does not exist'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}

public function newAction()
{
    $this->_forward('edit');
}

public function saveAction()
{
    if ( $this->getRequest()->getPost() ) {
        try {
            $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            $accessdeskModel = Mage::getModel('accessdesk/accessdesk');

            $accessdeskModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                ->setTitle($postData['title'])
                ->setContent($postData['content'])
                ->setStatus($postData['status'])
                ->save();

            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setAccessDeskData(false);

            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setAccessDeskData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            return;
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}

public function deleteAction()
{
    if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') > 0 ) {
        try {
            $accessdeskModel = Mage::getModel('accessdesk/accessdesk');

            $accessdeskModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                ->delete();

            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully deleted'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

}

Right now my suspicion is that this controller file is in the wrong place- Here is my Config.xml (in \app\code\local\Body1\AccessDesk\etc)

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Body1_AccessDesk>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Body1_AccessDesk>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <accessdesk>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Body1_AccessDesk</module>
                    <frontName>support</frontName>
                </args>
            </accessdesk>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <accessdesk>
                    <file>accessdesk.xml</file>
                </accessdesk>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <accessdesk>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Body1_AccessDesk</module>
                    <frontName>accessdesk</frontName>
                </args>
            </accessdesk>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <accessdesk module="accessdesk">
                <title>AccessDesk</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>

                <children>
                    <items module="accessdesk">
                        <title>Manage Items</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>accessdesk/adminhtml_accessdesk</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </accessdesk>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <accessdesk>
                            <title>AccessDesk Module</title>
                            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        </accessdesk>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>

        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <accessdesk>
                    <file>accessdesk.xml</file>
                </accessdesk>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <models>
            <accessdesk>
                <class>Body1_AccessDesk_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>accessdesk_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </accessdesk>
            <accessdesk_mysql4>
                <class>Body1_AccessDesk_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <accessdesk>
                        <table>accessdesk</table>
                    </accessdesk>
                </entities>
            </accessdesk_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <accessdesk_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Body1_AccessDesk</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </accessdesk_setup>
            <accessdesk_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </accessdesk_write>
            <accessdesk_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </accessdesk_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <accessdesk>
                <class>Body1_AccessDesk_Block</class>
            </accessdesk>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <accessdesk>
                <class>Body1_AccessDesk_Helper</class>
            </accessdesk>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>`

Comment: Did you log out of admin and log back in?

Comment: Also did you delete the cache and re-index?

Comment: please show us your code

Comment: Try naming your controller file `AccessdeskController` instead of `AccessDeskController`

Comment: Actually it turns out that naming my controller IndexController (and class code and config accordingly did the trick. do not know why it did not like AccessDeskController However Marius your suggestion did come closest to answering Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Clearing cache & logging out/back in to admin should solve your issue. Magento's adminhtml stores ACL privileges in session data - thus the need to relog.

For some interesting reading on what goes on behind the scenes grab a bag of popcorn and check out: http://alanstorm.com/magento_acl_authentication

Answer (score 2):

According @marius.You need to change class name space and file name of controller file

file `AccessdeskController` instead of `AccessDeskController`

same change need  also class name

```
Body1_AccessDesk_Adminhtml_AccessDeskController
```

should be `Body1_AccessDesk_Adminhtml_AccessdeskController`

Comment: Can you not have modules with upper case in the middle of the module name? E.g. MyCompany_MyModule. Is it better to have Mycompany_Mymodule?

Comment: Yes.it better to use First Letter upper & then all lower

Comment: AmitBera do you know what place `MyModule` type module names breaks the convention?

Comment: michel,little bit of busy now. Will be reply  soon

Comment: Amit, I found that it doesn't work in layouts `<block type="mycompany/adminhtml_mymodulebackend" />` will not work. It will become `Adminhtml/Mymodulebackend`.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure you've cleared your cache and logged in and out of the administration area
2) The URL translates to a controller in the module.
http://foobar.com/module/controller/action

e.g. http://foobar.com/kimit/catalog/text

- I open the KimIT module.
- Look in the controllers directory for catalogController.php.
- Search in there for the function textAction()